How would I create an equation given 2 variables and an output?
For a video game's documentation, I am testing the relationship between two values, m and d (where m is an MP value and d is a Defense value), and the damage a spell deals.
I already have the Damage values in the following tables:
Fire Spell Table:

Blizzard Spell Table:

Thunder Spell Table:

The portions that read N/A are entries that surpass the game's limit of 300 damage, so they could not be recorded properly.
The function would look something like f(x,y) = z. Since I already have the MP, Defense, and Damage values, is there a way that I can use those points to work backwards and create an equation? I did notice a pattern in these tables, where increasing both MP and Defense by a consistent amount each time results in the same Damage value, or in other words, the entire table just shifts over relative to the row above.
I have been trying to figure out a relationship by hand for a while, but I feel like there is an easier way to figure this out than banging my head against a wall until it works.
Thanks in advance!

Fire Spell
$$\text{damage}\approx A+Be^{K(d-m)}$$
where $A=0.265419$, $B=67.0939$, $K=-0.173805$

Blizzard Spell
$$\text{damage}\approx A+Be^{K(d-m)}$$
where $A=0.44404$, $B=94.7833$, $K=-0.174072$

Thunder Spell
$$\text{damage}\approx A+Be^{K(d-2m)}$$
where $a=0.0564723$, $b=33.633$, $k=-0.173464$

Notes:
Regressions solved using Desmos
The value of $K$ seems to be the same for all three spells, while $B$ appears to be in $1:2:3$ approximate ratio.
Note the $(d-2m)$ for the Thunder spell, as compared to $(d-m)$ for the other two.

Perfect! Thank you for the help!

Actually, how did you solve for x1, x2, and x3? As in how did you know it was (d-m) and (d-2m)?
Edit: Also, how did you find A? I was trying to plot these in Excel and I could only find the B and K values.

For the fire and blizzard, you can see that the values repeat when you move right by 1 step, and down by 1 step, showing that $d-m$ is constant for the cells that have same values. For the thunder however, you move right by 2 steps, and down by one to see the values repeat. Thus, there we have $d-2m$ constant for cells with same values.

After finding that the damage values can be expressed as a function of $d-m$ and $d-2m$, I simply plotted the damage values on the linked Desmos graph. The functions looked similar to $A+B\exp{(Kx)}$, so I set up a regression in Desmos. Regression tries to find the best possible values of $A,B,K$ that fit the data.
